# Updating Zero value with Previous values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `SQL Server 2014`... I have following scenario

[image]

I want to update these 0 (Zeros) with 1196 and 1124 and vice versa
Data Type of `PNO` is bigint and cursor is very slow because of huge records, please help or suggest any other query other than `CURSOR`

Comment: how do you know the order of the records?

Comment: add one more identity column or else use unique column and we can use while loop instead of curosr to update your records.

Comment: You can do it by using `LEAD()` or `LAG()`, but you definitely need an additional column which identify the order.

Comment: Let's suppose we have identity column is "ID" let's say 1 , 2 ,3 ......................N so how we loop through this ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to generate a table which has only the non-zero `PNO` values in it, and then `JOIN` that to the original table using the row from the `CTE` which has the maximum `id` less than the original table's `id` value. This can then be used to update the original table:

```
with cte as (
    select id, PNO
    from test
    where PNO != 0
)
update test
set PNO = cte.PNO
from test
join cte ON cte.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.id <= test.id)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3c3f8529f87386957059bc78b85a718f)

Comment: Thanks , little bit change c2.id <= test.id then it fulfill all my requirement

Comment: @KhuramJan sorry about that - I didn't pay enough attention to the output in the demo. I've corrected the answer and the demo.